# Plot surface of a cube in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to project a 3D cube onto a 2D image and I am looking for an effective way to draw the surface of this cube. I'd like to avoid using some of the existing solutions such as wire_frame, as this will be computationally heavy during projection.

Therefore I was wonder if anyone has seen a solution where given the corner of a box as such:

```
d = 0.5 #dimensions
    corners = np.array(
        [
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [d, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, d, 0.0],
            [d, d, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, d],
            [0.0, d, d],
            [d, 0.0, d],
            [d, d, d],
        ]

def visualize_cube(corners):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    ax.scatter3D(corners[:, 0], corners[:, 1], corners[:, 2], s = 100)
    plt.xlabel("X axis")
    plt.ylabel("Y axis")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

There is a simpler solution to draw the surface of this cube prior to projection. Has anyone come across a solution in MPL where given eight-points of a cube, you can generate the six faces of the cube?

Comment: What is the exact question? You already have plotted the cube.. what else is needed?

Comment: @viggnah, apologies if it was not clear - I'll update the question. You'll notice in the current code, all I have are the eight corners of the cuber, so during projection, I'm only projecting these corners. I'd like to find a way to represent the actual surface of the cube in mpl such that projection will be of the faces of the cube, not just the corners.